# Parse Json string to html divs using jquery

Tags: jquery, json

I have json string like this

`{"common_search":{"strBusinessName":"Sun Shine Vision","strAddress":"Amulia St Madhava Pharmacy Jn","intPhone":""}, "cache_table":{"Details":"Speedtrax,Ample's Bldg Off Banerji Rd., Amulia St,"}}`

And i have to set these data to my html divs for eg: i want to set common_search data to

```
$("#common_serachdiv").html('strBusinessName')
```

and cache_table data to `$("#cache_table").html('Details')` , Or i have to iterate through each array inside Json . How to do this ,

Thanks in advance .

Comment: Does this question have something to do with php?

Comment: NO i have to iterate this json string in javascript only

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to `parse json` before to use it.

```
var obj = $.parseJSON('{"common_search":{"strBusinessName":"Sun Shine Vision","strAddress":"Amulia St Madhava Pharmacy Jn","intPhone":""}, "cache_table":{"Details":"Speedtrax,Ample\'s Bldg Off Banerji Rd., Amulia St,"}}');
$("#common_serachdiv").html(obj.common_search.strBusinessName);
$("#cache_table").html(obj.cache_table.Details);
```

**[Fiddle Demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/nFUVs/)**

Comment: Glad to help you. Please don't forget to accept my answer by clicking the checkmark to the left of it.