# how to write/update the data in html page depeding upon the json response in ajax jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, windows-phone-8

i am working with javascript jquery. I m sending request to the url for getting json response and i want that json response should be displayed in another html page with some good format may be in table or smoother format.then how can i do that.and also i want to update data in my html page depending upon the json response dynamically.so how can i do that.and am working with phonegap then which technology should i use for server side ?

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "url",
    data: null,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function(data) {
        alert("success");
    }
}, error: function(jqXHR, exception) {
    if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
        alert('Not connect.\n Verify Network.');
    } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
        alert('Time out error.');
    } else if (exception === 'abort') {
        alert('Ajax request aborted.');
    } else {
        alert('Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText);
    }
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

replace with this code

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "url",
    data: null,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function(data) {
        alert("success");
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, exception) {
        if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
            alert('Not connect.\n Verify Network.');
        } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
            alert('Time out error.');
        } else if (exception === 'abort') {
            alert('Ajax request aborted.');
        } else {
            alert('Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Rather than the `alert("sucess")` you could use some code like this

`myDiv = document.getElementById('htmldiv');`

`myDiv.innerHTML = "Success";`

But basically just dynamically update part of your page. You could also display the responce see below, the result of that will depend on what is the results of the AJAX call.

`myDiv.innerHTML = jqXHR.responseText;`

Comment: i know this way..i am getting that response also but in my one form i m getting the list of merchant in json format by get method and i want to display that list in some other html page in table format and this list is changing everytime from server so whatever change is there it should be updated in that html table..how can i do this..?

Comment: What is the issue ? Converting JSON to a dynamic HTML Table OR the communication between Web pages ?

Comment: converting json to dynamic html table..how can i append the data so that it should be displayed in html page.?

Comment: I would parse the JSON and then use document.createElement to create required HTML then appendChild to add the HTML created into the page.

Comment: can u give me some link for this to get this information..?

Comment: Here are a couple of link to something similar   
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16209318/parse-json-string-to-html-divs-using-jquery

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22505712/cross-domain-json-parse-to-display-in-html-using-jquery-error     Hope this helps...